# htaccess RewriteCond and RewriteRule for not HTTPS

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've several rules in my htaccess file. 
With one block I change the behavour to HTTPS in any case, with the next block I will define a exception

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
  RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L] 

  # but not SOAP or APP-calls # 
  RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$
  RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^type=8800882$
  RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*(?:^|&))action=.*
  RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L] 
</IfModule>
```

The first block does it job.
But it isn't possible to force HTTP with setting parameter "type=8800882" or with adding parameter action to the request.

This is my second try, first I did this (worked, but is now broken):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
      RewriteEngine On
      RewriteBase /
      # all should be HTTPS #
      RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
      RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^type=8800882$
      RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(.*(?:^|&))action=.*
      RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L]
    </IfModule>
```

How can I make a exception for not HTTPS if there is parameter type=8800882 or parameter action=*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following rule :

```
RewriteEngine on


#exclude /?action=.* and ?type=8800882
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\?(?:type=8800882|action=.*) [NC]
 #http to https
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !443
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [NE,L,R]
```